# Error-using the generic type AspNet.Identity.usermanager<Tuser> requires 1 type of argument?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

I am getting this error when am trying to use UserManager.CreateAsync(user, reg.password) code. Please help.
and one more thing i installed the package aspnet.identity.core package. But i cant reference it. When i try to reference it using Using i can't find the package.

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = reg.username };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, reg.password);
              if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
```

Comment: Thank you. What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: the title of this post

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that your code is trying to call `CreateAsync()` directly on the `UserManager<TUser>` class, whereas `.CreateAsync()` needs to be called on an *instance* of `UserManager<TUser>`.

In the boilerplate code provided with the Identity package, this is accomplished with a property defined in the `AccountController`:

```
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get
    {
        return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }
    private set
    {
        _userManager = value;
    }
}
```

Do you have a property like this available in your controller?